# Create a regular expression pattern to match all lines that don't contain form

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

I want to create a regular expression to match all lines that don't contain "form."

For example, for the below

```bash
form.id
    </div>
form-group
      <label for="url">URL</label>
form.url
    </div>
```

I tried to use look ahead, but it doesn't work.

The patter I use is

```
^.*(?!form\.).*$
```

This actually matched all lines including those lines like form.id

Comment: It should be: `^(?!.*form\.).*`

Comment: The obvious trivial solution is to extract all lines which don't match the regex `form`

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern it can find form keyword on the initial ".*" part and find a not containing "form." substring in any other part of the line.

You should make the negative lookahead contain all the line to avoid such a match.

This should do your job since it looks at all line from the beginning to find longest sequence which does not match "form." then adds the rest of the line.

```
^(?!.*form\.).*$
```

Comment: You can use your regex with paranthesis to see which part is being matched to better understand the logic. (check your pattern here: https://regex101.com/) (for example: `^(.*)(?!form\.).*$`  in this regex you will see the first paranthesis takes the line all)